# EF1 navigation properties not working?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, .net-3.5

My entity model was generated from the existing database. There is a many-to-many junction table picked up and hidden by EF.

[image]

The relationship is definitely working because this query returns 2 users as expected.

```
    public IQueryable<User> FindUsersByGroupID(int group_id)
    {
        return db.Users.Where(u => u.Groups.Any(g => g.Group_ID == group_id));
    }
```

But when locating a user that is part of the above result set the Groups navigation property count is 0. I shouldn't have to explicitly join.. right?

```
    public User FindUserByID(int id)
    {
        return db.Users.First(u => u.User_ID == id);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
db.Users.Include("Groups").First(u => u.User_ID == id);
```

or load it after with

```
if (!user.Groups.IsLoaded)
{
    user.Groups.Load();
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Do you know if this is the same behavior in EF4? It seems counter-intuitive that a navigation property is exposed when the other table is not yet included.

Comment: @ryan with EF4, you can activate LazyLoading to do this automatically

Comment: Now what about inserts? I need to associate a new user with a group. I would expect to be able to set User user = new User(); user.Groups.Group_ID = 1; Perhaps I need a sort of Include() in my partial user class constructor?

Comment: @ryan you have to add the Group entity to the Groups EntityCollection

Comment: Thankyou :) I was trying to = instead of .Add